# how to print set of sets in java?

Tags: java, printing, hashset

```
HashSet<Set<Set<int[]>>> Sa=new HashSet<Set<Set<int[]>>>();
```

Now, i need to print Sa.using single iterator I am not able to print

```
Iterator<Set<Set<int[]>>> iter = Sa.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(iter.next());
}
```

this isn't working

Comment: Printing `int[]` is awkward period.  Try switching to a `List<Integer>`.

Comment: You have three layers of sets. You'll need three iterators inside three neested loops. Why do you insist on using only one iterator?

Comment: Please don't name variables with upper-case - a very bad practice. Upper-case is reserved for Class names. use CamelCase instead: [Java Naming Conventions](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=java%20naming%20conventions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you shouldn't be using primitive data types like `int` with Generic classes. So in place of `int[]` use `List<Integer>`.

Now if you really just want to use **one** `Iterator` then you can use a bunch of `for-each` loops like this -

```
for (Set<Set<List<Integer>>> aSa : Sa) {
        for (Set<List<Integer>> bSa : aSa) {

            Iterator<List<Integer>> iter = bSa.iterator();

            while(iter.hasNext()) {
                System.out.println(iter.next());
            }
        }
 }
```

**Full test code -**

```
    HashSet<Set<Set<List<Integer>>>> Sa = new HashSet<>();

    // Creating dummy data

    // Two List of Integers
    List<Integer> listInt1 = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> listInt2 = new ArrayList<>();

    // Populating the list
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        listInt1.add(i);
        listInt2.add(i+30);
    }

    // Data structure of Sa.
    Set<List<Integer>> setOfIntLists1 = new HashSet<>();
    Set<List<Integer>> setOfIntLists2 = new HashSet<>();

    setOfIntLists1.add(listInt1);
    setOfIntLists1.add(listInt2);

    setOfIntLists2.add(listInt2);
    setOfIntLists2.add(listInt1);

    Set<Set<List<Integer>>> setOfset1 = new HashSet<>();
    Set<Set<List<Integer>>> setOfset2 = new HashSet<>();

    setOfset1.add(setOfIntLists1);
    setOfset1.add(setOfIntLists2);

    setOfset2.add(setOfIntLists2);
    setOfset2.add(setOfIntLists1);

    // Adding data to Sa
    Sa.add(setOfset1);
    Sa.add(setOfset2);

    for (Set<Set<List<Integer>>> aSa : Sa) {
        for (Set<List<Integer>> bSa : aSa) {

            Iterator<List<Integer>> iter = bSa.iterator();

            while(iter.hasNext()) {
                System.out.println(iter.next());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
[0, 1, 2, 3]

[30, 31, 32, 33]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here it is, assuming you have multiple levels to your `Set` objects and your array, you have to iterate over each level.

```
Iterator<Set<Set<int[]>>> iter = Sa.iterator();
Iterator<Set<int[]>> innerIter;
Iterator<int[]> deepIter;
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    innerIter = iter.next().iterator();
    while(innerIter.hasNext()){
        deepIter = innerIter.next().iterator();
        while(deepIter.hasNext()){
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(deepIter.next()));
        }
    }
}
```